# How to insert google form uploaded image of google drive which is a link in a google sheet in google doc template placeholder?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

```
function createPDF(info){
    const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1rvM4ll4W9nNr253u58fy_M0yuoEb-Y_3");
    const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1ED3xHz07MvbsDdaDzD32f_Yh_ZiXcxEv");
    const templateDoc= DriveApp.getFileById("1SngiJBfyaSeMu6P8TtZfmMkTVlODnR-WJkCOG7xwa9Q");

    const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);

    const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = openDoc.getBody(); 
  
  body.replaceText("{firstname}", info['First Name'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{middlename}", info['Middle Name'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{lastname}", info['Last Name'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{dob}", info['Date of Birth'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{age}", info['Age'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{gender}", info['Gender'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{bloodgrp}", info['Blood Group'][0]);
  
  

  var imagePlaceholder = '{photo}'; // Replace with the placeholder you used in the template for the image
  var imageElement = body.findText(imagePlaceholder).getElement();
  var imageParent = imageElement.getParent();
  
  // Insert the image into the document
  imageParent.removeChild(imageElement);
  imageParent.insertImage(0, imageBlob);
  

  body.replaceText("{sign}", info['Signature'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{ts}", info['Timestamp'][0]);

  openDoc.saveAndClose();
  const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['First Name'][0] + " " + info['Last Name'][0]);
  tempFolder.newTempFile.setTrashed(true);
  return pdfFile;
}
```

I wanted to have respective section in image as id photo or similar in other document template which came through forms. I have links in spreadsheet but when i try to replace, it replaces the text url but not the photo. I dont know how to achieve. Could you please help. I know i need to have a placeholder code not the text replace code. But i dont know how to write that. Could you please correct the photo section of my code?
Here is the code.

Comment: In your script, it seems that `imageBlob` is not declared. I'm worried that you might have miscopied your current script. How about this?

Comment: Ahh!! I really m sorry. I don’t know but I need this. I believe it is in capable hands of yours. Could you please help me out by writing few lines to correct the code. I am a complete newborn in this field but m wanting to learn more.. could you please help me out 

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Tanaike! I would like you to look into the matter and find a solution if possible. 
I want your help. 
I want to have that imageBlob function to display the picture in template of google doc which has a placeholder named photo. I have done this in google sheets app script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But, I would like to try to understand your question. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution.